# Understanding “die bald lasen, bald exzerpierten, bald in ihre Aktentaschen einlegten”

Tags: pronoun, relative-clause

The question is on the relative clause as highlighted in this passage from Kafka’s *Der Verschollene.*

> An einem runden Tisch saßen drei Herren, der eine ein Schiffsoffizier in blauer Schiffsuniform, die zwei anderen, Beamte der Hafenbehörde, in schwarzen amerikanischen Uniformen. Auf dem Tisch lagen, hochaufgeschichtet, verschiedene Dokumente welche der Offizier zuerst mit der Feder in der Hand überflog, um sie dann den beiden anderen zu reichen, **die bald lasen, bald exzerpierten, bald in ihre Aktentaschen einlegten**, wenn nicht gerade der eine, der fast ununterbrochen ein kleines Geräusch mit den Zähnen vollführte, seinem Kollegen etwas in ein Protokoll diktierte.

**QUESTION**

Can we put another *die* as follows so it may refer to the documents.  (I assume the first *die*, already there, refers to “the other two,” i.e. the harbor officials.)

> die **die** bald lasen, bald exzerpierten, bald in ihre Aktentaschen einlegten.

Comment: It is already clear from the context that it's most probably the documents that are read - No urgent need to mention that (Also it seems to be of no interest whatsoever to the message what actually has been read and the form taken tells us that - The guys are just busy doing there business) Also thanks for reminding us of *exerpieren* - Didn't read that in a long time.

Comment: @tofro: Dann lies es nochmal. NIcht, dass Du es mit exzerpieren verwechselst!

Comment: Lesen und Tippen sind zwei verschiedene Künste. Lesen kann ich eigentlich ganz gut....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you don’t have to, and it would subtly change the meaning.

The last part before the bold type refers to “the two other” (officers), so it is clear the bold part refers to *what the two officers are doing*.

If you add the second *die*, the tone changes subtly to stress what the two officers are doing *to the documents they are given*. A better choice to insert here would be *diese*, to avoid the repetition of *die*.

Since the whole section is about describing what the people are doing, with the documents apparently being of no big importance, they are omitted from the highlighted subsentence.

This is gramatically correct, even if it sounds somewhat artifical today – not so much in Kafka’s time though.

Comment: Or *sie* instead of *diese*.

Comment: Wieso zeigt das Verhalten, dass die Dokumente nicht von großer Wichtigkeit sind?

Comment: @userunknown: Weil *dieses* die Dokumente zum Objekt des Satzes machen würde. Im Moment sind es die Offiziere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider your insertion (marked with angle brackets) an improvement, since it would introduce a third reference to the same documents using again a new word.

> verschiedene Dokumente (1) welche (2) der Offizier zuerst mit der Feder in der Hand überflog, um sie dann den beiden anderen zu reichen, die [die (3)] bald lasen, ...

Since *welche* can't be repeated without adding additional explanation, the omission seems the better choice, in my opinion followed by Jans proposal *diese*.

If not literature, but an explaining text looked like this, I would recommend separation in several sentences, repeating *Dokumente* instead.

Answer (score 1):

Jein ;) Es ist „die die“ keine gute Wahl, denn ein zweites Relativpronomen kann ein Nebensatz nicht haben, und als Demonstrativpronomen wäre das zweite „die” bestenfalls umgangssprachlich zulässig. Man könnte aber je nach Geschmack „die sie” oder „die diese” schreiben. Beides sind mögliche Varianten.

Die nächste Frage ist, ob dieses zusätzliche Wort hilfreich ist. Ich denke, dass DevSolar richtig darauf hinweist, dass es den Fokus leicht verschiebt. Wenn wir aus den Nebensätzen Hauptsätze machen, dann erscheint

> Bald lasen sie, bald exzerpierten sie.

mir monotoner als

> Bald lasen sie sie, bald exzerpierten sie sie.

was eher nach einer zielgerichteten Handlung klingt. Jedoch ist

> Sie legten in ihre Aktentaschen ein.

nach meinem Empfinden kein vollständiger Satz, während

> Sie legten sie in ihre Aktentaschen ein.

einer ist, auch wenn ich „hinein“ statt „ein” erwarten würde. Daher halte ich rein grammatikalisch Deine Lösung für besser als Kafkas, die mir ein wenig holprig erscheint.